# How to convert class object to json string in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, object, xcode5

1.I create class objects then add value to my class with this code

```
csJastorPollQuestion *pq = [[csJastorPollQuestion alloc] initWithID:@"01" Name:@"AAA"];
```

2.I shown "csJastorPollQuestion" in NSLog it's present

```
#<csJastorPollQuestion: id = (null) { ID = 01; Name = AAA; }>
```

3.I convert "csJastorPollQuestion" to json string with this code

```
NSData *jsd = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:pq options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&er];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsd encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

4.When I run my project it's shown error this

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
```

5.What is the right way for convert "csJastorPollQuestion" to json string?

Comment: Stick it in a dictionary.  JSON requires the top level object be either a dictionary or an array.

Comment: i want some example can you provide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` method only works on objects that `NSJSONSerialization` knows how to convert to JSON. That means:

- The top-level object must be an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`
- Objects contained must be instances of `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSNull`.
- Dictionary keys must be `NSString`s
- Numbers must not be infinite or `NaN`.

You need to convert to a dictionary or array representation to use this method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should reflect your own object to NSDictionary and used NSJSONSerialization convert to JSON string.

Reflect from attributes:

```
    - (NSDictionary *)dictionaryReflectFromAttributes
    {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            unsigned int count = 0;
            objc_property_t *attributes = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);
            objc_property_t property;
            NSString *key, *value;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                property = attributes[i];
                key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
                value = [self valueForKey:key];
                [dict setObject:(value ? value : @"") forKey:key];
            }

            free(attributes);
            attributes = nil;

            return dict;
        }
    }
```

Convert to JSON string:

```
    - (NSString *)JSONString
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [self dictionaryReflectFromAttributes];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
        if (jsonData.length > 0 && !error)
        {
             NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             return jsonString;
        }
        return nil;
    }
```